# Perform a swap of all children of nodes at a given depth

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, depth

I'm trying to write a function that performs a swap on all the children of nodes at a given depth.

Say we have a tree like this:

```
   1 
  / \ 
 2   3
```

And an `array` containing the depth of nodes I want to perform a swap on.

If the array contains `1` then we swap all the childs of nodes at that depth. The tree would then look like this:

```
  1 
 / \ 
3   2
```

My function looks like this:

```
public void swap(TreeNode node, int[] swaps, int i, int arraySize, int depth) {
        if(arraySize == 0) return;

        if(depth < swaps[i]) {
            swap(node.left, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
        }

        if(depth == swaps[i]) {
            TreeNode temp = node.left;
            node.left = node.right;
            node.right = temp;
        }

        if(depth != swaps[i]) {
            swap(node.right, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
        }

        if(depth == swaps[i]) {
            TreeNode temp2 = node.left;
            node.left = node.right;
            node.right = temp2;
        }
    }
```

When I run this method on the example tree, and perform a `inorder traversal` of the tree, it gives me `2 1 2`

Answer (score 0):

Swap the line `node.right = temp2` with the line `node.left = node.right`.

Example:

```
public void swap(TreeNode node, int[] swaps, int i, int arraySize, int depth) {
    if(arraySize == 0) return;
    // Swap left
    if(depth < swaps[i]) {
        swap(node.left, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
    }
    // Swap right
    if(depth != swaps[i]) {
        swap(node.right, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
    }

    // Swap us
    if(depth == swaps[i]) {
        TreeNode temp2 = node.left;
        node.left = node.right;
        node.right = temp2;
    }
}
```

Comment: updated now. You were partially right. Now i get `2 1 3`. But after I use the swap function I'm supposed to get `3 1 2`

Comment: You are repeating the swap code twice. Remove one of them and it should be correct.

Comment: hm - that worked. But with a bigger tree this will cause a problem. The way it is now, I call recursively first with `node.left` then with `node.right`.

Comment: I would suggest calling left then right, then perform the swap on your current level. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: do you mind updating your question with code, just so I'm not the one misunderstanding?

Comment: Updated, I'm not entirely sure when you want to swap and how you want to handle larger trees but based on what you had this is how I would structure it.